# How to show total time of highlighted tracks in status (more than 1) in Foobar 2000?

Tags: windows-10, foobar2000

I am using [Foobar 2000](https://www.foobar2000.org) and this my status bar :

```
%codec% | %bitrate% kbps | %samplerate% Hz | %channels% | • %playback_time%[ ~ %playback_time_remaining%][ = %length%]
```

I would like to add on the right corner: total time of a) entire playlist or b) selection of tracks, in `hours:min:sec`

Answer (score 0):

Probably not 'exactly' what you want, but in Foobar2000 you can add that value to the status bar by right-clicking on it and selecting that option:
[Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnJV2.png)